Show that there does not exist any holomorphic function on the open unit disk and continuous on the closed unit disk with the given property.

Let $\mathbb D : = \left \{z \in \mathbb C\ :\ \left \lvert z \right \rvert < 1 \right \}.$ Prove that there is no continuous function $f : \overline {\mathbb D} \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$ and $f(z) = \overline z$ for all $z \in \partial \mathbb D.$

My Attempt $:$ By Cauchy Integral Formula we get $f^{(k)} (0) = 0$ for any $k \geq 0.$ But since $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(k)} (0)} {k!} z^k$ we have $f(z) \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb D$ and this cannot happen since $f$ is continuous on $\overline {\mathbb D}$ and $f(z) = \overline z$ for all $z \in \partial \mathbb D.$
Could anyone please have a look at my solution? Thanks in advance.

How did you get $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$?

(The solution is fine, but the usual Cauchy integral formula requires the path to lie in the region of analyticity, so some elaboration is needed.)

@copper.hat$:$ Is it due to homotopy version of Cauchy's theorem.

I don't know whether you can just apply Cauchy integral formula on the boundary. The version that I know does not allow it.
However, the function $g(z) := zf(z)$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ fulfils the following for all $z \in \partial\mathbb{D}$:
$$
g(z) = z f(z) = z\bar z = \lvert z \rvert^2 = 1
$$
As a holomorphic function that is real on the boundary, it has to be constant. Therefore $zf(z) = 0%$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ as $g(0)=0$. From this we conclude that $f=0$. This contradicts the boundary condition.

The linked statement seems to suppose that $f$ is analytic on the boundary as well. OP does not suppose that.

In my opinion, the answer does not use the assumption that you mentioned. So everything still works, even with only continuous boundary

Yes you're right, the answer there also works in the more general setting we have here.

By Cauchy-Goursat, $\int_{B_r(0)} f(z) dz =0$ for every radius $r<1$. Convince yourself that by continuity, this entails $\int_{B_1(0)} f(z) dz =0$ as well. (This is the nontrivial part, you need that the smaller circles uniformly approach the big one, and actual epsilon-estimates.  Cf. Cauchy's integral theorem and domain boundaries).
But it's very well known that $\int_{B_1(0)} \bar z dz = \int_{B_1(0)} z^{-1} dz =2\pi i\neq 0$.

This certainly works.
